# Why is a there about 1-2px gap between my caption and image?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a any margin so I'm a confused as to what the cause is and how to remove it. You can't see the image but you can see the grey border with the gap between the caption and image still https://jsfiddle.net/nyftp2b7/11/

```css
.caption-clr {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<figure class="main-image">
  <a href="img/cannabislegalmap.png">
    <img src="img/cannabislegalmap.png" width="100%" alt="Image of a map of states were recreational cannabis is legal">
  </a>
  <figcaption class="caption-clr">States were recreational cannabis use is legal.
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: It's possible your browser might be adding margin/padding around the a tag?

Comment: All of the HTML elements come with a default style. You'll want to learn how to use the "inspector" in your browser's devtools. In many browsers, you can right-click on an element and select "Inspect" to see what CSS is applied.

Comment: I've used inspector thats why I'm confused, I'm not seeing any margin on the image or any parent elements that would be effecting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `float: left;`

On the image, this solves the problem like so;

```
.main-image img {
float: left;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks do you know it did? Like do you know the technical reason?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply Brandon, I have not been online since i answered your query. Browser automatically add spacing (margin and or padding) to an image, among other things, same as body. Floating the images overrides these styles. You can also fix this by using display block, however this may not working depending on how you have styled the rest of the site. I hope this explains it well enough.